# Disable the trigger in manage package

Tags: trigger, managed-package

My client have installed a managed package in his salesforce org. Now he want to disable some of the trigger in this manages package. From my researcher I am able to understand that the trigger can only be disabled by the developer who have developer the manage package. Or is their any other way to disable the trigger. Just what to confirm is their any other option from our side to disable the trigger.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no other option to disable it once the managed app is installed.

Always as a best practice you create a custom setting flag for your subscriber  to activate and deactivate a trigger so you can control in the subscriber org

Comment: Hi @Mohith, if there's a trigger in managed app (which expired or marked expired in LMA) then does the managed trigger auto turn inactive on app expiration date? or do I need to handle app expiration logic check in managed trigger ?